# how to join two javascript in one page?

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with javascript. I have two javascript files working currently working well, but when I join them into a single file, the first query works and not the second one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jcps.fader(200, '#switcher-panel2', '.set2');
    jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel3', '.set3');
    jcps.fader(400, '#switcher-panel4', '.set4');
    jcps.fader(500, '#switcher-panel5', '.set5');
 });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lista1").als({
        visible_items: 3,
        scrolling_items: 2,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        circular: "yes",
        autoscroll: "no",


        easing: "linear",
        direction: "left",
        start_from: 0
    });

    //logo click
    $("#logo_img").click(function () {
        location.href = "http://als.musings.it/index.php";
    });

    $("a[href^='http://']").attr("target", "_blank");
    $("a[href^='http://als']").attr("target", "_self");
});
```

Comment: It could be jQuery versions conflict problem. Are you using different jQuery versions? Try to rind out jQuery.noConfilict().

Comment: are these two javascipts on the same page ?

Comment: The problem is that on your page you are using two $(document).ready(). insetead of that define it only once and put everything into it. Have a look at my answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is very little information; could you give us the code as it is when you "join them in a single page"? Is that all you have in your code? Where and how do you put the script in your HTML?

Anyway, my first guess would be to merge both functions as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jcps.fader(200, '#switcher-panel2', '.set2');
    jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel3', '.set3');
    jcps.fader(400, '#switcher-panel4', '.set4');
    jcps.fader(500, '#switcher-panel5', '.set5');

    $("#lista1").als({
        visible_items: 3,
        scrolling_items: 2,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        circular: "yes",
        autoscroll: "no",


        easing: "linear",
        direction: "left",
        start_from: 0
    });

    //logo click
    $("#logo_img").click(function()
    {
        location.href = "http://als.musings.it/index.php";
    });

    $("a[href^='http://']").attr("target","_blank");
    $("a[href^='http://als']").attr("target","_self");
});
```

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Glad it helped! Could you validate my answer then, please?

Answer (score 0):

Update your javascript as mentioned below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        SetFader();

        SetAttributes();

    });

    function SetFader() {
        jcps.fader(200, '#switcher-panel2', '.set2');
        jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel3', '.set3');
        jcps.fader(400, '#switcher-panel4', '.set4');
        jcps.fader(500, '#switcher-panel5', '.set5');

    }

    function SetAttributes() {
        $("#lista1").als({
            visible_items: 3,
            scrolling_items: 2,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            circular: "yes",
            autoscroll: "no",


            easing: "linear",
            direction: "left",
            start_from: 0
        });

        //logo click
        $("#logo_img").click(function () {
            location.href = "http://als.musings.it/index.php";
        });

        $("a[href^='http://']").attr("target", "_blank");
        $("a[href^='http://als']").attr("target", "_self");

    }

</script>
```